# react-admin: having problems with 2 tabs using the same table or source

Tags: reactjs, list, datagrid, show, react-admin

hi im trying to make a react-admin list  in which contains 2 tabs each getting data from the same table and i think i am encountering a "colliding keys error" the first tab is fine but when i click on the second tab it takes m to a random location in my demo how do i fix this?

```
export const AssetSubdivisionExpand = (props) => (
      <TabbedShowLayout {...props}>
          <Tab label="Filtered Data (true)">
              <ReferenceManyField
                  addLabel={false}
                  reference="A"
                  target="B"
                  filter={{ B: props.record.id, C: true }}
                  sort={{ field: "D", order: "ASC" }}
              >
                  
          <List
              {...props}
              actions={false}
              bulkActionButtons={false}
          >
                      <Datagrid {...props}>
                          <DateField label="date" source="D" />
                          <BooleanField label="status" source="E" />
                      </Datagrid>
                  </List>
              </ReferenceManyField>
          </Tab>
          <Tab label="Filtered Data (false)">
              <ReferenceManyField
                  addLabel={false}
                  reference="A"
                  target="B"
                  filter={{ B: props.record.id, C: false }}
                  sort={{ field: "D", order: "ASC" }}
              >
                  <List
                      {...props}
                      actions={false}
                      bulkActionButtons={false}
                  >
                  <Datagrid {...props}>
                      <DateField label="date" source="D" />
                      <BooleanField label="status" source="E" />
                  </Datagrid>
                  </List>
              </ReferenceManyField>
                      </Tab>
      </TabbedShowLayout>
      );
```

i tried rewriting it using a combination of fragments and tabs to fix it but that just showed both tabs in one page

Comment: im using react 3.19 btw